# net windows sample application which store data offline and store to main db when there is network

Tags: c#, windows, frameworks, synchronization

I'm developing a windows application. Reason for developing in Windows is because of network connectivity. In remote places they face network issue. I'm trying to build a windows application using sync framework.I want a sample application which uses the same. Could you please help me with this.
If anyone have already done this could you please share me the source code it would be great help!

Comment: Hi Shetty, SO is a place where people answer the questions related to code problem, e.g something you tried but not worked...this question is like how to do which i think you should gooogle.

Comment: @JigarPandya i have googled a lot but coudnt find any source of help. I atleast need how to start with it. A helpfull link atleast which i can refer.